# Use sed and regex to isolate data

Tags: regex, logging, sed, filter

Hehey

i'm on the way to learn about sed and regex and grouping and how to isolate data from a file with that.

Ok i wrote a sed command there give me, all the IPs in the auth.log and write the ips in the logips.log file, so i need to grouping the regex and take the second (ip) group.

```
sed 's/(.*)([0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3})(.*)/\/2/g' /var/log/auth.log > logips.log
```

But i have every time the whole auth.log in my logips.log. After 2 hours of thinking and seeking, i'm here and asking.

i hope someone can push me in the right direction to solve this.

happy greetings

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the expected output.

Comment: hmm what i expect was only the ip addresses from the auth.log, what i got was a copy of the auth.log in the logips.log.

Comment: Yes, post an example with a few lines from your `auth.log` and then post an example of what you would like your results to look like

Comment: ok, in the auth.log is: `Sep 18 14:06:28 tartaros sshd[2042]: Received disconnect from 85.7.143.X port 4444:11: disconnected by user
Sep 18 14:06:28 tartaros sshd[2042]: Disconnected from user hades 85.7.143.X port 4444
Sep 18 14:06:28 tartaros sshd[1935]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user hades` and in the logips.log i expect only: 85.7.143.X

Comment: Questions should be self-contained and not require reading in comments to understand the problem. Please move your sample data into the body of your Q and delete your comments. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To get all IP from the auth.log, try `grep` instead.

```
grep -o -E "[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}" auth.log
```

- `-o` output only match
- `-E` extended regex
- `[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}` match IP